# CDbCriteria parameters with regex character classes

Tags: php, mysql, regex, yii

I'm trying to use CDbCriteria in Yii with a `REGEXP` condition. I'm using the MySQL markers for word boundaries, being `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]`, however this seems to conflict with Yii because I get "Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens". I assume this is because the word boundary markers use a colon, which is also what is used for binding parameters. Is there a way around this?

```
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->addCondition('col regexp "[[:<:]]:app[[:>:]]"');
    $criteria->params = array(':app'=>$app);
    $details = Post::model()->find($criteria);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP will not replace placeholders inside strings, i.e within quotes. As in:

```
$criteria->addCondition('col = :app'); // param can be replaced
$criteria->addCondition('col = ":app"'); // param can't be replaced
```

Therefore we need to use mysql's [CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function to actually generate the string for regexp, instead of providing the string ourselves, like so:

```
$criteria->addCondition('col regexp CONCAT("[[:<:]]", :app, "[[:>:]]")');
```

OR, bind the entire regex itself:

```
$criteria->addCondition('col regexp :regexp');
$criteria->params = array(':regexp'=>'[[:<:]]'.$app.'[[:>:]]');
```