# CGridView filter whole words

Tags: mysql, regex, yii, criteria, cgridview

I want to modify filtering of title columnt in **CGridView**.
Now it's:

```
$criteria->compare('title',$this->title,$partialMatch=false);
```

but i want to match whole words using this query:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_post WHERE title REGEXP '[[:<:]]$this->title[[:>:]]'
```

In post model search function i made

```
if ($this->title)
{
    $criteria->select = 'title';
    $criteria->condition = 'title REGEXP "[[:<:]]:filter_word[[:>:]]"';
    $criteria->params = array(':filter_word'=>$this->title);
}
return new CActiveDataProvider('Post', array(
    'criteria'=>$criteria,
    'sort'=>array(
        'defaultOrder'=>'status, update_time DESC',
    ),
```

but always i get **no results found** when filtering

Comment: possible duplicate of [CDbCriteria parameters with regex character classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893178/cdbcriteria-parameters-with-regex-character-classes)

Comment: As in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893178/cdbcriteria-parameters-with-regex-character-classes you should include the whole regexp (including `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]`) as your `params`.

Comment: Updated, but now i get messagebox with Error 500: Object of class CDbCriteria could not be converted to string.

Comment: On what line does the error occur? Add the error message + line of code to the question.

Comment: Now is fine, in my code i has got one additional '$'

Comment: Ok. I've rolled back your edit to match with the duplicate question.